# Return back rights to set security descriptor for SCManager

Tags: windows-server, sc.exe

On Windows server 2016 I made an incautious action. Using my account which belong to a builtin Administrator group I set security descriptor for SCManager:

```
sc sdset scmanager "D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;BA)(A;;CC;;;AC)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)"
```

After reading documentation I have figured out that default permission value for builtin administrators is `(A;;KA;;;BA)`. That means who are in group Administrators can set security descriptor.

With `(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;BA)` I was restricted to set security descriptors for SCManager.
How can I return back the rights?

Comment: While reading deeper I start to understand that only Administrators group can change the security descriptor and now no one can do it. Please, say that I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue delete the registry branch:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder\Security
```

then reboot the server.

Comment: Real livesaver this, thx